# Find the image of $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z-2|<2$ and $|z-1|>1\}$ under the map $z\mapsto \frac{1}{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, conformal-geometry

As the title explains, I'm trying to solve a question which asks me to find the image of

$\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z-2|<2$ and $|z-1|>1\}$

under the map $z\mapsto \frac{1}{z}$.

I find it really hard to understand the intuition behind these kinds of questions, so it'd mean a lot if you could help explain the answer to this particular question and perhaps give me an overview of some strategies to solve similar problems.

Comment: What happens *geometrically* with a complex number under that mapping? Think about Euclidean transformations.

Comment: With Fractional Linear transformations, you really want to see what happens to lines and circles. In your case, see what happens to the bounding circles. That'll give you an idea where the intersection goes. To figure out what happens to the circle, take 3 points and find their images.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Möbius transformation.  They take generalized circles to generalized circles.

If $z=re^{i\theta}$, then $\frac1z=\frac1r e^{-i\theta}$.

Going back to the first point,  we know the boundaries $\mid x-2\mid=2$ and $\mid x-1\mid=1$ go to generalized circles. Since $0$ goes to $\infty $, it appears that both circles go to lines ($0$ lies on both circles).

Try a couple of other points.  $2\to\frac12$ and $1+i\to\frac1{1+i}=\frac12-\frac12i$.  So $\mid z-1\mid=1$ goes to the vertical line through $\frac12$ and $\frac12-\frac 12i$.

Next, $\mid z-2\mid=2$ goes to the vertical  line through $\frac14$ and $\frac1{2+2i}=\frac14-\frac14i$.

Then as to the region between the two circles (the region of interest), just take a test point.   Like $\frac52$, for instance. $\frac52\to\frac25$.  This is the region between the two vertical lines.  An infinite vertical strip.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: There is probably a better way to do this but I am no complex analysis kiddo

let $S=\{z\in \Bbb C : |z-2|<2 : |z-1|>1\}$ and $T=\{A\cos(\alpha)e^{i\alpha} : A \in (2,4) : \alpha \in (\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})\}$

If $A\cos(\alpha)e^{i\alpha} \in T$ then $$ |A\cos(\alpha)e^{i\alpha}-1|=\sqrt{ \left(A\cos^2(\alpha ) -1\right)^2 + \left(A\sin(\alpha)\cos(\alpha)\right)^2} $$ $$=\sqrt{(A^2-2A)\cos^2(\alpha)+1}>1$$ as $A>2$ and $\alpha \in (\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$

Furthermore $$ |A\cos(\alpha)e^{i\alpha}-2|=\sqrt{ \left(A\cos^2(\alpha ) -2\right)^2 + \left(A\sin(\alpha)\cos(\alpha)\right)^2} $$
$$=\sqrt{(A^2-4A)\cos^2(\alpha)+4}<2$$
as $A<4$ and $\alpha \in (\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$

Now if $z\in S$ let $z=Re^{i\alpha}$. By the triangle inequality $Re(z)>0$ thus $\alpha \in (\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$ and $\cos(\alpha)>0$ thus we can let $R=A\cos(\alpha)$. As $|z-1|>1$
$$\sqrt{(A^2-2A)\cos^2(\alpha)+1}>1$$ which implies $ A>2$

As $|z-2|<2$ $$\sqrt{(A^2-4A)\cos^2(\alpha)+4}<2$$ which implies $A<4$

This proves that S=T
now if $z=A\cos(\alpha)e^{i\alpha} \in S$ then $$1/z=\frac{1}{A\cos(\alpha)}e^{-i\alpha}=\frac{1}{A}- \frac{i \tan(\alpha)}{A}$$
as $\alpha$ varies the vertical line $x=\frac{1}{A}$ is formed and as then letting $A$ vary you get the set $W=\{ x+iy : x,y \in \Bbb R : 1/2\gt x\gt1/4\}$

Parameterisation is a nice method to solve these sort of problems btw. I found the parameteriation I showed you by considering the circles $|z-a|=a$ and subbing   $z=a e^{i\theta}$ and then using the trig half angle identities to get it into a nice form.